# shaking tableviewcell in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-animation

I am trying to Animate the `cell` when did select the row at `indexPath` and I am succeeded with this code in `didSelectRowAtIndexpath` method

```
TableViewCell1 *cell = (TableViewCell1 *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

CABasicAnimation *shake = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
[shake setDuration:0.1];
[shake setRepeatCount:3];
[shake setAutoreverses:YES];
[shake setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:
                     CGPointMake(cell.center.x - 5,cell.center.y)]];
[shake setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:
                   CGPointMake(cell.center.x + 5, cell.center.y)]];
[cell.layer addAnimation:shake forKey:@"position"];
```

but in storyBoard with segue method this Animation Was Disappear, and when I clicked the row it will directly go to next view.

my requirement is when I clicked row the particular row should shake 3 themes and after that it go to next view. please any one Help me...

Comment: You can add segue to view (not to cell selection method) and than call manually (`self performSegue:`) after animation completed in `didSelectRowAtIndexpath `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you created segue to the next view directly from table view cell,remove that segue and connect from current view to next view,set identifier to your segue and then code as following

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    CABasicAnimation* shake  = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    [shake setDuration:0.1];
    [shake setRepeatCount:3];
    [shake setAutoreverses:YES];

    [shake setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:
                         CGPointMake(cell.center.x - 5,cell.center.y)]];
    [shake setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:
                       CGPointMake(cell.center.x + 5, cell.center.y)]];
    [cell.layer addAnimation:shake forKey:@"position"];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.3
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(loadNextView)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];

}
-(void)loadNextView
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegueIdentifier" sender:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)getCellFocused:(int)row table:(UITableView*)table{



     [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{


            UITableViewCell *cell = [table cellForRowAtIndexPath:inedexPath];

            CAKeyframeAnimation * anim = [ CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform" ] ;

            anim.values = @[ [ NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeTranslation(-10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) ], [ NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeTranslation(10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) ] ] ;

            anim.autoreverses = YES ;

            anim.repeatCount = 2.0f ;

            anim.duration = 0.1f ;



            [ cell.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:nil ] ;



        } completion:nil];

 }
```